# Detecting which UIAlertView was clicked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview

i need to pop up alert when my application loaded... I called it didfinished launching..
after clicking ok button need to show another alert message i use clickedButtonAtIndex...

Now when I clicked the ok button its calling again and again.. the alertview..

I need to call only once... what to do?

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the tab bar controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    viewControllersList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Alow this app to use your GPS location"
    delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{


    if (buttonIndex==0) {
        NSLog(@"NO");
    }
    else    {

        NSLog(@"Yes");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Do you want's to receive Push messages."
        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

}
```

@thanks in advance.

Comment: set delegate:nil in second alertView

Comment: k welcome always........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define each UIAlertView and in the delegate look for which Alert to respond to:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if(alert1) {
        if (buttonIndex==0) { 

            NSLog(@"NO"); 
        } else {

            NSLog(@"Yes");
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Do you want's to receive Push messages." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
    } else {

        /*  the second alertview  using the same buttonIndex  */
    }

}
```

Comment: @Kiran this is the way when you code for both alert button code(In case you need to perform any action on click of second alert).

Answer (score 4):

set `delegate:nil` in second alertView
I mean

```
if (buttonIndex==0) { NSLog(@"NO"); } else {

NSLog(@"Yes");
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Do you want's to receive Push messages."
delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also add a tag to your AlertView and te check the tag later on the clickedButtonAtIndex method

```
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"All local datawill be erased. Erase local data?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Erase", @"Cancel",nil];
        alert.tag =123; // added the tag so we can prevent other message boxes ok button to mix up 
        [alert show];
```

then

```
    -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex ==0 && alertView.tag==123){
       // Do what ever you wish
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to receive the location, just request it and the system will automatically show the message for you. Follow this example:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
// Create a location manager instance to determine if location services are enabled. This manager instance will be
// immediately released afterwards.
CLLocationManager *manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
if (manager.locationServicesEnabled == NO) {
    UIAlertView *servicesDisabledAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Services Disabled" message:@"You currently have all location services for this device disabled. If you proceed, you will be asked to confirm whether location services should be reenabled." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [servicesDisabledAlert show];
    [servicesDisabledAlert release];
}
[manager release];
```

}

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Listings/Classes_AppDelegate_m.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007801-Classes_AppDelegate_m-DontLinkElementID_4

Same for push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

though u got many implementation solutions already ...but i think better practice would be to assign a tag to each of your AlertView and before detecting the button tapped check the tag of invoking AlertView.Hope this helps.
@Gerard:Though both location manager and push notification service raise system generated messages ,these can be checked off by users not to be shown again.So better HIG complaint method is application generating message whenever push or location manager are required.